# Check if usb connectors in motherboard work?

Tags: usb, motherboard, connector

My motherboard ([ASUS M2N MX SE](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2NMX_SE/)) has two internal usb connectors.

Until some days ago I had a PC case with two frontal usb sockets, and a card reader with an additional ubs socket. The two usb sockets were connected in one internal usb connector, and the card reader (with its usb socket) was connected to the other.

The two usb sockets never worked. The card reader and its usb socket worked at the beginning, but the usb socket in the card stopped working. I don't remember if the card reader stopped working or not (I don't use it very much).

Now I have a new PC case.

I connected the two usb sockets of the new case in one internal usb connector, and the old card reader to the other.

And now, only one of the two usb sockets work. And the card reader has its led turned on, but doesn't read cards and its usb socket doesn't work.

Then, I think it's a problem of the internal usb connectors of the motherboard.

But how can I be sure if it's that, or a problem of the card reader and both cases, or maybe a driver problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have confirmed the headers do not work by the fact two separate cases had problems

Comment: I figured I'd leave a comment to let you know this same thing happened to my board I had (same model). The 'front' USB went out first, eventually all of my on-board USB ports didn't work (no power, no lights, nothing). The controllers were still recognized by the OS (linux/windows) leading me to think I could potentially use them but after multi-meter and logic probe attempts, I ended up having to install a PCI USB card (luckily had a PCI slot open).